# Converting from Numbers to Words in Pentaho Reports

Tags: javascript, mysql, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am new to Pentaho Reporting System. I wish to ask if there is any function that one can use to convert numbers to words. My reports are all generated in pdf format. I am using MySQL server.

Comment: there is nothing as such to directly convert number to words.
but in pentaho data-integration you can use value mapper step and map your number individually to words.
through it is not ideal way but if you have 5 to 10 numbers only then you can try.

Comment: I would have googled for javascript code that solves your problem, and use that in a 'Modified Java Script Value' step. Or a solution in java, and use a 'User Defined Java Class' step, although that is more difficult.

Comment: can i create a package in java and import to pentaho. is it going to be possible to use classes of this package in pentaho system.